# Arcobjects: how do I find if a line intersects a polygon?

Tags: arcobjects

I have one closed Polyline: "rectangle" and an open Polyline: "line".
Both Polylines may be Z aware.
What is the best way to find if the "line" intersects the "rectangle" in the XY plane?
That is I want a 2D (XY) test for intersection. I do not need the actual coordinates of any intersection(s).

Comment: You need to intersect then and check the output. If they intersect you will get some output, otherwise you will get a null geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemple in VB.NET:

```
Dim Rel As IRelationalOperator = CType(MyPolygon, IRelationalOperator)
Return Rel.Disjoint(MyPolyline)
```

I suggest not using ITopologicalOperator.Intersect, because as the ESRI [doc](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003vs000000) says:

> Since ArcGIS 9.2, Intersect has a larger cost - it takes longer to run
>   the method.  Therefore, it is a better approach to test if the two
>   geometries are disjoint before calling Intersect.